# Virtualized application's access to fileserver from target machine

Tags: virtualization, file-server

I'd like to set up a headless Linux server running a file server, and virtualization software to deliver Windows applications to various machines running Windows and Linux within my LAN (preferably in a seamless mode).

*Is it possible to have the virtualized software access files within the file server from the target machine? (if I have a document saved on the file server, can I access it through the virtualized application)*

Also... *License issues aside, is it feasible to serve multiple instances of the same (Windows) application to different users from a home server? (no more than 3 to 4 at a time)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't apply to Linux, but we use Microsoft's App-V. The virtual apps can see mapped drives, printers, etc. just like installed apps can. Also, we served thousands of clients from one 2.8 GHz server when we first started in 2007.

Your mileage may vary depending on the virtualization software chosen, but I hope this helps in a general app virtualization sense.